# How does Santino connect with the first John Wick movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-2

According to the first John Wick, John was able to get out of the assassin's world by doing one final job, which was a final job ordered by Viggo, upon which Viggo's organized crime empire was built. But how does Santino's marker fit into the picture?

It seems as though John gave the marker to Santino to exit the assassin's world, which I thought he did by doing Viggo's final job.

So how did John leave his assassin's life? By giving Santino the marker? Or by doing that final job for Viggo?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So how did John leave his assassin's life? By giving Santino the marker? Or by doing that final job for Viggo?

## Both

**Santino did *something* to help Wick in completing his last impossible task for Viggo.**

> SANTINO: "If not for what I did on the night of your impossible task, you wouldn't be here."
>
> ...
>
> SANTINO: "You came to me, I helped you."

It's not explained **what** Santino did but it doesn't really matter...the marker was given and had to be repaid.